Openvpn on fedora40 raises error on systemd process but works well in regular command prompt
Although on ubuntu everything is work well when I tried to start openvpn as systemd service in fedora40, its work well in prompt :
sudo /usr/sbin/openvpn --verb 9 --suppress-timestamps --nobind --config /etc/openvpn/client/client.conf

but gives error when prompt following systemctl
 sudu systemctl start openvpn-client@client 

Here are my system config :
Openvpn version : 2.6.9
Copyright (C) 2002-2023 OpenVPN Inc <sales@openvpn.net>
Compile time defines: enable_async_push=yes enable_comp_stub=no enable_crypto_ofb_cfb=yes enable_dco=yes enable_dco_arg=yes enable_debug=yes enable_dependency_tracking=no enable_dlopen=unknown enable_dlopen_self=unknown enable_dlopen_self_static=unknown enable_fast_install=needless enable_fragment=yes enable_iproute2=no enable_libtool_lock=yes enable_lz4=yes enable_lzo=yes enable_management=yes enable_pam_dlopen=no enable_pedantic=no enable_pkcs11=yes enable_plugin_auth_pam=yes enable_plugin_down_root=yes enable_plugins=yes enable_port_share=yes enable_selinux=yes enable_shared=yes enable_shared_with_static_runtimes=no enable_silent_rules=yes enable_small=no enable_static=yes enable_strict=no enable_strict_options=no enable_systemd=yes enable_werror=no enable_win32_dll=yes enable_wolfssl_options_h=yes enable_x509_alt_username=yes with_aix_soname=aix with_crypto_library=openssl with_gnu_ld=yes with_mem_check=no with_openssl_engine=auto with_sysroot=no

Linux Distro :Fedora release 40 (Forty)

The prompt below works which requires sudo  :
sudo /usr/sbin/openvpn --verb 9 --suppress-timestamps --nobind --config /etc/openvpn/client/client.conf

but when I run systemctl start openvpn-client@client
I get following result says : Error opening configuration file: client.conf
× openvpn-client@client.service - OpenVPN tunnel for client
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn-client@.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/service.d
             └─10-timeout-abort.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2024-05-15 23:13:38 +03; 21min ago
       Docs: man:openvpn(8)
             https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage
             https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO
    Process: 62703 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --suppress-timestamps --nobind --config client.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 62703 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 32ms

May 15 23:13:38 fedora systemd[1]: Starting openvpn-client@client.service - OpenVPN tunnel for client...
May 15 23:13:38 fedora openvpn[62703]: Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: client.conf
May 15 23:13:38 fedora openvpn[62703]: Use --help for more information.
May 15 23:13:38 fedora systemd[1]: openvpn-client@client.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 15 23:13:38 fedora systemd[1]: openvpn-client@client.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 15 23:13:38 fedora systemd[1]: Failed to start openvpn-client@client.service - OpenVPN tunnel for client.

Here is service file content
cat /lib/systemd/system/openvpn-client@.service
[Unit]
Description=OpenVPN tunnel for %I
After=syslog.target network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target
Documentation=man:openvpn(8)
Documentation=https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage
Documentation=https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO

[Service]
Type=notify
PrivateTmp=true
WorkingDirectory=/etc/openvpn/client
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --suppress-timestamps --nobind --config %i.conf
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_IPC_LOCK CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_NET_RAW CAP_SETGID CAP_SETUID CAP_SETPCAP CAP_SYS_CHROOT CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE
LimitNPROC=10
DeviceAllow=/dev/null rw
DeviceAllow=/dev/net/tun rw
ProtectSystem=true
ProtectHome=true
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

File permissions are :
sudo ls -l /etc/openvpn/client
 
-rw-------. 1 root root 3863 May 15 22:58 client.conf

What  cause this error ?
Thanks in advance...

The process runs with different SELinux security contexts. Run ls -lZ on your config file to see what the . in its file permissions actually means.
You might need to run restorecon on the config file to re-apply the "correct" file context per SELinux configuration. (I'm assuming SELinux is set up to apply the correct process context automatically, but there's a SELinuxContext= service setting in case that's needed…)
